# Using 'vanilla' JS to set CSS property on selected elements

Tags: javascript, css

**JavaScript Newbie** so the following question maybe 'dumb'.

For my work I do a little GreaseMonkey scripting to make our eCommerce store back end a little more friendly to our customer service team. Normally I'd make a new or better UI for them setup a special role or something, but with this current system, this is literally not an option.

Specifically I make a selection of links `visibility: hidden`, as they trigger some reporting functions which can lock up the backend till the reports are completed.

Up to this point I have had the script load jQuery, which is fine but not ideal. Then I dug in and saw that the interface was built using YUI, while this is already loaded, the syntax is weird to me, and I don't like it much, plus it is now not supported.

Recently I found the [Plain JS](https://plainjs.com/) site, which describes how to use 'vanilla' JS to do jQuery like things. *Splendid!* I thought, *Now I can just write simple JS without extra dependencies or libs!* But this is not quite the case.

I have tried the following:

```
var links = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("a")); // creates an actual array from the node list returned by document.query
var links_to_hide = links.slice(14, 22); // gets just the bits we want to affect from the array, and is still an array

// ok so 'links_to_hide' is an array, and it is an array of 'a' anchor tags.
// if I go into the inspector and set the visibility property it affects the tag but doing it via scripting seems to not work.
// so if links_to_hide is an array it should be possible to 

for(var i = links_to_hide.length; i <= links_to_hide.length; i++){
  links_to_hide.style['visibility'] = 'hidden';
}
// this for loop doesn't seem to actually affect anything
```

What am I missing. Near as I can tell this should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
for(var i = links_to_hide.length; i <= links_to_hide.length; i++){
  links_to_hide.style['visibility'] = 'hidden';
}
```

To this

```
for(var i = 0; i < links_to_hide.length; i++){
  links_to_hide[i].style['visibility'] = 'hidden';
}
```

Comment: I'm still coming up to speed on JS, why does adding the `[i]` make a difference?

Comment: The variable links_to_hide is an array type, it is like below;

links_to_hide = [link_element1, link_element2, link_element3, ...]

So you reach each of this array items by links_to_hide[i] where i is 0,1,2 ...

Comment: Oh! That makes total sense! Appreciate the insight.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't using `i`

```
links_to_hide[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop should be like below:

```
for(var i = 0; i < links_to_hide.length; i++){
   links_to_hide[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
```